# Check if Unix DateTime is within 5 Minutes

Tags: javascript

I have a Unix datetime like - 1432467713

I'm trying to check if it was created within the last 5 minutes.

I've tried the following:

```
var originaltime = '1432467713';
var time = (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
if(originaltime < time) {
   console.log('within 5 mins');
}
```

I know it has holes in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to subtract five minutes, and you want `>`, not `<`:

```
var originaltime = 1432467713;             // No quotes
var time = (Date.now() / 1000) - (5 * 60); // Five minutes ago
if(originaltime >= time) {
   console.log('within 5 mins');
}
```

---

`Date.now` returns milliseconds-since-the Epoch. It's on all modern browsers. For old browsers, you can shim it:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() {
        return +new Date();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

5 minutes is 300 seconds, so just test if the original time is after the current time minus 300.

```
if (originaltime > time - 300)
```